# Postgresql with Hibernate: could not determine LocalDate type in jpql query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I migrated from hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final to 
hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final because I want to use LocalDate from java 8 Date/Time APi in jpql for parameters, like this:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM TransactionHistory t WHERE (t.account.id=:account)" + "AND (:dateFrom IS NULL OR t.date >= :dateFrom) AND (:dateTo IS NULL OR t.date <= :dateTo) order by t.date asc")
List<TransactionHistory> findByAccountIdAndDate(@Param("account") Long id,
                                                @Param("dateFrom") LocalDate from,
                                                @Param("dateTo") LocalDate to);
```

In build.gradle file I have next necessary dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final'
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.1'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'
```

When I run server I get the next stack trace:

```
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy218.findByAccountIdAndDate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor378.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
        at com.my_company.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor317.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy218.findByAccountIdAndDate(Unknown Source)
        at com.my_company.ibank.account.AccountService.doTestIntegrationTask(AccountService.java:830)
        at com.my_company.ibank.account.AccountService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dc3e5dc0.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
        at com.my_company.ibank.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor317.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
        at com.my_company.ibank.account.AccountService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d97ec4f4.doTestIntegrationTask(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor371.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:379)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1488)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:118)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2476)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2189)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:71)
        ... 90 common frames omitted
```

So postgres can not determine data type of parameter $2, which is must be LocalDate as described in query above, please help to solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem with JPA and LocalDate parameters.

The solution is to cast the value before the `IS NULL` comparison.

In your example:

```java
@Query("SELECT t FROM TransactionHistory t WHERE (t.account.id=:account)"
    + " AND ( CAST(:dateFrom AS date) IS NULL OR t.date >= :dateFrom)"
    + " AND ( CAST(:dateTo AS date) IS NULL OR t.date <= :dateTo)"
    + " order by t.date asc")
List<TransactionHistory> findByAccountIdAndDate(
    @Param("account") Long id,
    @Param("dateFrom") LocalDate from,
    @Param("dateTo") LocalDate to);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
```

Example:

```
@Column
  @Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
  private LocalDate valueDate;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What fully qualified class is LocalDateConverter? My IDE show 4 items to select.

Comment: @DirkSchumacher : If you are using spring framework, then you should import LocalDateConverter from  (Jsr310JpaConverters) i.e. org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters package